# What is the difference of the following two mathematical sentences? (Walter Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis)

Tags: soft-question

I am very poor at English.
But I am reading Walter Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis now.

In the book, I found the following sentence:

> A point $p$ is a *limit point* of the set $E$ if *every* neighborhood of $p$ contains a point $q \neq p$ such that $q \in E$.

I cannot understand why "**the** set $E$" instead of "**a** set $E$".

What is the difference in meaning between the following two mathematical sentences?

(1)

> A point $p$ is a *limit point* of **the** set $E$ if *every* neighborhood of $p$ contains a point $q \neq p$ such that $q \in E$.

(2)

> A point $p$ is a *limit point* of **a** set $E$ if *every* neighborhood of $p$ contains a point $q \neq p$ such that $q \in E$.

Comment: There's no difference.

Comment: No difference really. For the first may be the set $E$ was already introduced so "the" would be used to refer to that specific one.

Comment: Thank you very much, Chris Custer and Pratyush Sarkar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no fundamental difference; to say "the set $E$" or "a set $E$" are both equally valid, grammatically, and Rudin isn't referring to a special or particular set either. It's just how some people word things sometimes.

While not particularly mathematical, this did remind me of another Stack Exchange question I saw recently. You might find it worth looking at: [here ya go](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/190987/the-jesus-who-said-why-is-there-a-definite-article-before-the-proper-name-j)

Comment: Thank you very much, Eevee Trainer.